# Generating thumbnails (Preview

Tags: java

I am looking desperately for a Java library that would be able to generate thumbnails for a large number of file types. Like Office Suite documents, Open Office Documents, PDF, Images etc... The thumbnails has to be readable.

From my understanding .net has hooks to call windows for doing exactly this but the code has to be platform independent (hence java)

I have found some libraries for image thumbnail generation some for word document but nothing that seems very good.
I am looking a one does it all library for generating the thumbnails does it exist?

Comment: See the answers provided in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244164/resize-an-image-in-java-any-open-source-library.

Comment: That link is good but only deals with image and image resizing. There is nothing about other type of documents.

Comment: to my knowledge there is no universal library creating thumbs of various document types. for pdf you can have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844961/create-thumbnail-image-for-pdf-in-java .. otherwise you can go the workaround to generate a temporary pdf out of your documents and then create your thumb

Comment: sorry, i meant to give you this link here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4392640/thumbnail-of-a-pdf-page-java