# Generate Pdf pages thumbnails

Tags: android, pdf, thumbnails

Hiii
I wanted to know about generating thumbnails in pdf in android. I want all the thumbnails of the pdf to be displayed when pdf is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

[Andpdf](http://andpdf.sourceforge.net/)  is a port of pdf renderer so I think you can easily [use this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844961/create-thumbnail-image-for-pdf-in-java/2844994#2844994) to get this done.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to display PDF page in thumbnails using muPDF. Please check this link [https://github.com/libreliodev/android.](https://github.com/libreliodev/android)

Enjoy!!