# Java Swing - PDF Thumbnail Viewer

Tags: java, swing, pdf, ftp, thumbnails

I'm kinda new in programming and I'm trying to learn everything by myself.
Currently I'm working on a project to sort all my bills and other stuff.
I managed it to updload the bills as PDF files onto a FTP Server.
I'm displaying all outgoing money in a JTable and now I'd like to see a Thumbnail of the PDF
in the right part of my swing GUI after i selected a table row.

**Here is what I was thinking of:**

1. Get the selected row via a clickListener, read the bill number, which is the same number the file is called on the FTP (e.g. Number: "20130012" / File: "20130012.pdf").
   Download the file from the FTP and save it somewhere temporary?!
2. and now I need to display the pdf in my grid layout but how =) ? If
   it is a picture I could use the Image Icon right? But how do I get
   the effect with a pdf?

As soon as I click on the thumbnail, I'd like to open up a pdf reader to see the actual file.

Sorry if this is to less information... just let me know if you need further information.
I'd really appreciate a few answers =)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [`ListSelectionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html) to determine which `JTable` row was clicked and fetch its PDF file. If fetch latency is a problem, use [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/). Once you [create a thumbnail](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2844961/230513) image of each page in the selected row's PDF, you can display them in a `JList` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13754697/230513). Display the selected page at full size in your implementation of [`ListSelectionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html).

Comment: Okay that worked so far, but now I'm displaying the Image of the pdf right next to the table. But when I'm trying to click the next bill I'll get a fileNotFoundException because the file is somehow used. I mean im showing it in the gui and when I try to download the next image and overwrite the old one I get that exception. Do I need to produce a temp file or something like that?

Comment: Not sure; `File#createTempFile()`, which abstracts host OS variations, may be the right choice.

Comment: thanks alot =). It's working now. I download the PDF, create a temp file and copy the PDF within the temp file. do display the pdf im using the temp file. thanks again