# Coldfusion cfpdf Thumbnails

Tags: pdf, coldfusion, thumbnails

Operating System: Linux 6.4
ColdFusion 11

I am trying to create a "thumbnail" from a pdf provided by a customer.

```
<cfpdf
    action="write"
    source="Customer.pdf"
    destination="output.png"
    saveOption="full"
    overwrite="yes"
    />
```

The Customer's pdf has a black "overlay" with white lettering.
When the thumbnail is generated, I get a white background with white lettering.

The files was created by Adobe Illustrator CS5.
I can't have every customer jump though a laundry list of instructions,
just to process the customer's files.

This reproducible on Linux and Windows.
Adobe has confirmed the problem.
Adobe's Developers have problems communicating in English
and keep telling me, nothing is wrong with ColdFusion.
I am sorry, but I don't speak any language from South East Asia.
(I think Adobe has moved ColdFusion development to India, but I don't know.)

The pdf is 7 megs, so I am concerned about posting the file.

Repeat, I need a ColdFusion Solution, Linux Solution or Adobe to fix ColdFusion.

Any ideas?  Please.

Forgive the frustration, but it has been a month long struggle.

Comment: Since CF can do Java easily, have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844961/create-thumbnail-image-for-pdf-in-java ?

Comment: I have done pdf thumb images with CF...Forget it.  It is super intensive on resources specially when you have a directory of PDFs (since you are not saying in your post if it works or doesn't work (explicitly or what it is doing) (only inferred from context and tone)).  Anyways, I think Henry has a better direction for you.

Answer (score 0):

Print your pdf using Adobe PDF as the printer. Then run the code, you will be able to get the thumbnails