# Create thumbnail image for PDF in Android

Tags: java, android, pdf, thumbnails, image-generation

I'm looking for a Java library that can take a PDF and create a thumbnail image (PNG) from the first page in an Android Mobile Device.

I found this [Create thumbnail image for PDF in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844961/create-thumbnail-image-for-pdf-in-java) but this will not work for android as it is dependent on AWT.

Please help me with the free support lib in android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Apache PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/).

> The Apache PDFBox™ library is an open source Java tool for working
>   with PDF documents. This project allows creation of new PDF documents,
>   manipulation of existing documents and the ability to extract content
>   from documents. Apache PDFBox also includes several command line
>   utilities. Apache PDFBox is published under the Apache License v2.0.

In itself, it is not compatible with Android so you may want to have a look at the Android port - [PdfBox-Android](https://github.com/Birdbrain2/PdfBox-Android) library.

If you want a web service, [Datalogics PDF WebAPI](http://www.datalogics.com/products/pdf/pdfwebapi/) is an option.

Comment: *In itself, it is not compatible with Android so you may want to have a look at the Android port*